# How to get a Modal to appear on my website using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get a Modal to appear on my website using Bootstrap 4. Somehow it's not appearing no matter what I try.

Below is the HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
         href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
         integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
          crossorigin="anonymous">
                

        <!--Custom CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button class="btn btn-primary"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch modal
      </button>
      
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                
             </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Text in Modal</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
                    
        
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

The Navbar works just fine. Maybe there is a doc missing from Bootstrap? Thanks for your input.

Comment: Remove the `fade` class

Comment: Seems to work fine in your question